# Regex for positive integer or an asterisk

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that would accept an interger parameter or an asterisk for all days of the month - ideally this should be limited to `1-31` as well.:

```
if [[ ! $DAY_OF_MONTH =~ ^[0-9]|*+$ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: DAY_OF_MONTH parameter must be a positive integer or an asterisk"
  exit 1
fi
```

However, it keeps failing and I see the error message on the output.

Comment: `[[ $DAY_OF_MONTH =~ ^[0-9]|[012][0-9]|3[01]|[*]$ ]] ||  echo "ERROR: DAY_OF_MONTH parameter must be a positive integer or an asterisk" >&2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the 2 alternatives, escape the asterix (and use a single occurrence if that is in the error message) and make the pattern for possible days in a month more specific.

```
if [[ ! $DAY_OF_MONTH =~ ^((0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])|\*)$ ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: DAY_OF_MONTH parameter must be a positive integer or an asterisk"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I needed to escape it. I did update the question because I think day of the month is a better example since it could contain double digits. In which case I don't think I can specify `[1-31]` in the regex.

Comment: @dokgu No, it does not work like that. Matching 1 - 31 is like `(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])`

Comment: I see, that explains it. Although I think it's not the prettiest solution.